# Hash from "email+salt " as a token to verify email

Tags: salt, email-validation, sha256, sha, saltedhash

I'm verifying user email address. 
The way most people tell  is to create some unique token store it in db and 
send to user.

I'm doing it with just hashing (sha256) email addres with sitewide salt
and sending this hash to user.

Am i missing something or is this enough to verify?

Comment: E-mail or e-mail address?  (Are you just confirming a user's e-mail address?)

Comment: e-mail address- Just confirming

Comment: more info on the context in which you're using this would be helpful. As written, it seems that a third party could intercept an email to the user containing the token, and then use the token with a spoofed From address to reply with an email that would verify, but not be from the actual user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things that might be worth a look (or not).

If someone finds out your salt, then they can reconstruct your hashes and flood your system.  In this case you'd want to make sure that a user requested addition of their e-mail address to whatever you're creating.  (That is, I wouldn't get rid of storing the hash in the DB altogether.)

Also, if the salt is the same, the hash will be the same if they request again from that same e-mail address.  Do you want a different hash each time a request is made, even for the same e-mail address?  You could concatenate the server date/time to the e-mail address before you hash it to make it different each time.

Comment: adding the datetime has the added benefit that you can use it to 'expire' the token after some set time...say 24 hours.

Comment: @hatchet:  I *almost* wrote that in. :) Can't the expiration be accomplished too by recording the request time in the DB?

Comment: you're right. I was thinking encrypt/decrypt, not matching hashed values.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that and if nobody gets the serverside salt, it's save. In the end it's email validation, and if you don't need to do it for legal reasons, there is no need to make it more complicated.

But it depends on your goals. Do want it to be extra safe? Do you want to be easy to implement? Do you want it easy to maintain? Are you thinking about execution time of your scripts?

BTW: One very nasty thing when having a long link in an email: There may be email cients which break your link, so maybe add the code along with the link and if the code is not completly transfered through the link, have a form where the user can add the code.